# Theming taxonomy nodes?

Tags: 6, theming, nodes, taxonomy-terms

Is it possible to theme a node based on taxonomy the same way you can theme a node based on its content type (something equivalent to node-news.tpl.php for example) or do I need to organize my content by content type to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can add new "[template suggestions](http://drupal.org/node/223440)" using a preprocess function. Here's an [article with more details](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1336146&seqNum=8).

[Here's another example](http://adaptivethemes.com/page-template-suggestions-for-taxonomy-vocabs), but for different templates based on the vocabulary, rather than the term.